# Navigation component for Custom navigation Drawer

Tags: navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Navigation Component library. But now i am getting stuck at one point.
i have created custom navigation drawer with recycler view . Now i want to move to the next fragment on adapter item click. How can achieve that with Navigation Component libarary.

Here is my adapter item click. Here  i have tried to create navigation click but its not working.

```
override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
    when(position){
        0->{
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.homeFragment)
            binding!!.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }

        1->{

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem, did u find any solution?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad no man didn't find solution so after that i switch to default navigation

Comment: I made a menu with items that has same id ... then I set the menu to a bottom navigation and I set the bottom navigation visibility to gone ... after that I connect navController to bottom navigation , then same as your code , I switch the position and enable item of bottom navigation

Answer (score 1):

Use

> Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.homeFragment)

Comment: what is view here ?

Comment: if you are using it in a fragment then view is accessible  in onviewcreted , if not and u are using this code in activity then u must use Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

Comment: Crash: "ID does not represent a view inside this activity".